# How to allow a file download only from a local desktop application?

Tags: download

I need to find a solution to allow a file download (It's an .exe file for an app update) only if the request comes from a desktop application and to block requests if they come from a web browser.

How to manage that?
Thank you. Nina

Comment: What do you mean by "local"?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There's a few methods that you could use:

1) Download via the website but require a API Key, basically you could build a page in php that requires a key and the desktop applications contain that key.

2) You could host the file on FTP with username and password, and only have the applications with the username and password - this is by far the easiest way.